# vim mapping from q! to Q!

Tags: vim, vi, vimrc

I was trying to map 'q!' to 'Q!' in .vimrc ?  I tried the following but not working. 
:command Q! q!
Please provide any suggestion to mitigate this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to give

```
:command Q q
```

Similarly, you can do for other commands like,

```
:command WQ wq
:command W w
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  ":command Q q" is working perfectly, but the problem creates when I try to map the key "q!" (which is quit without implementing the changes.)

Comment: In that case, you could simply do ZQ in Normal mode although it takes some rewiring to remember! :)

Comment: Thank you.  However It is better to stick with q!.

Answer (score 2):

This worked perfectly for me:

```
:command-bang Q q<bang>
```

From vim's help ([`:h command-bang`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-bang)):

```
Special cases                           :command-bang :command-bar
                                        :command-register :command-buffer
There are some special cases as well:

        -bang       The command can take a ! modifier (like :q or :w)
```

and

```
Replacement text

The replacement text for a user defined command is scanned for special escape
sequences, using <...> notation.  Escape sequences are replaced with values
from the entered command line, and all other text is copied unchanged.  The
resulting string is executed as an Ex command. [...]

The valid escape sequences are
        [...]
        <bang>  (See the '-bang' attribute) Expands to a ! if the
                command was executed with a ! modifier, otherwise
                expands to nothing.
        [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
:cmap Q! q!
```

Maps `Q!` in command mode to `q!`.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine.  But If I take time to type ! after Q, It doesn't work. When I type Q! quickly it automatically gets changed to q!.  Nevertheless  I am not that slow in typing. Thank you once again.